# Solving a second level functional equation over all functions $g$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations, recursive-algorithms, recursion, transcendental-equations

I am trying to find a closed form expression $f$ such that

$$f(g(x+1) - g(x)) + f(g(x) - g(x-1)) = f(g(x))$$

For all functions $g$

I have concluded that for polynomials

$$2^{n+1}f(0) = f(a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 ... a_nx^n)$$

But I am not sure how to extend this to rational functions etc... Any suggestions? My derivation of the aforementioned identity for polynomials is below:

My Derivations:

As an example if we set $g$ to $x$

$$f(x+1 - x) + f(x - x  + 1) = f(x) \rightarrow 2f(1) = f(x)$$

Naturally we can attempt to pull a little more data out of this so we try $g = cx$ which yields:

$$ 2f(c) = f(cx)$$

Now I can attempt functions for the form $g = cx + d$ which yields

$$ 2f(c) = f(cx + d) $$

Therefore it may be true that $ f(g(x) + e) = f(g(x)) \forall e \in C $

We can now attempt to build up this functional for the quadratic functions $g = ax^2 + bx + c$ by noting

$$a(x+1)^2 + b(x+1) + c - ax^2 - bx  - c = a(2x + 1) + b$$

and therefore

$$f(2ax + a + b) + f(2ax - a + b) = f(ax^2 + bx + c)$$

Thus:

$$2f(2a) + 2f(2a) = f(ax^2 + bx + c) \rightarrow 4f(2a) = f(ax^2 + bx + c)$$

From here it is easy to see that one can recursively take any polynomial $g = a_n x^n + ... + a_0$ and evaluate

$$f(a_n x^n + .... + a_0)$$

as simply $$2^n f(n! a_n)$$ and furthermore by observing that for constants

$$f(0) + f(0) = f(c) \rightarrow f(c) = 2f(0)$$

We can show now

$$f(a_0 + a_1x + ... + a_nx^n) = 2^{n+1}f(0)$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we can find such a function $g$, that:

(i)$g(x)=x$

(ii)$g(x+1)=g(x-1)=0$

if we substitute it to equation $f(g(x+1) - g(x)) + f(g(x) - g(x-1)) = f(g(x))$ you have:

$$f(-x)+f(x)=f(x)$$

So for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ you have:

$f(-x)=0$

So $f(x)=0$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: If the functions g are restricted to the continuous functions does this change?

Comment: No, it doesn't change, moreever it's possible to write down sample $g$ in direct form: $$g(t)=-x(t-x-1)(t-x+1)$$